# Pytorch: Difference between indexing and torch.stack

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

Is there any advantage for using indexing vs using `torch.stack` when constructing a tensor in pytorch?

#### Indexing

```py
out = torch.empty(length, n)
for ii in range(length)
    out[ii] = f(ii)
```

#### `torch.stack`

```py
out = [f(ii) for ii in range(length)]
out = torch.stack(out)
```

### Benchmark

Benchmarking the two, it seems like `torch.stack` is consistently more than twice as fast as indexing:

```
[------------ 8 -------------]
             |  nojit  |  jit 
1 threads: -------------------
      index  |  113.9  |  99.1
      stack  |   60.5  |  51.6

Times are in microseconds (us).

[------------- 32 ------------]
             |  nojit  |   jit 
1 threads: --------------------
      index  |  450.4  |  385.8
      stack  |  198.1  |  174.5

Times are in microseconds (us).

[------------- 128 -------------]
             |  nojit   |   jit  
1 threads: ----------------------
      index  |  1805.9  |  1555.8
      stack  |   779.2  |   688.7

Times are in microseconds (us).

[----------- 256 -----------]
             |  nojit  |  jit
1 threads: ------------------
      index  |   3.6   |  3.0
      stack  |   1.5   |  1.4

Times are in milliseconds (ms).

[----------- 512 -----------]
             |  nojit  |  jit
1 threads: ------------------
      index  |   7.9   |  6.0
      stack  |   3.0   |  2.7

Times are in milliseconds (ms).

[----------- 1024 -----------]
             |  nojit  |  jit 
1 threads: -------------------
      index  |   14.4  |  12.6
      stack  |    6.1  |   5.1

Times are in milliseconds (ms).
```

Benchmark script

```py
import torch
import torch.utils.benchmark as benchmark


def index(arr: torch.Tensor, length: int):
    # arr: (n, )
    (n,) = arr.shape

    out = torch.empty(length, n, device=arr.device)
    out[0] = arr

    for ii in range(1, length):
        out[ii] = out[ii - 1] + arr

    return out


def stack(arr: torch.Tensor, length: int) -> torch.Tensor:
    # arr: (n, )
    arrs = [arr]
    for ii in range(1, length):
        arrs.append(arrs[-1] + arr)

    return torch.stack(arrs, dim=0)


index_jit = torch.jit.script(index)
stack_jit = torch.jit.script(stack)


def main():
    torch.random.manual_seed(1234)
    n = 256

    x = torch.randn(n).cuda()

    lengths = [8, 32, 128, 256, 512, 1024]

    timers = []
    for length in lengths:
        label = f"{length}"
        globals_dict = {"x": x, "length": length}

        t_index = benchmark.Timer(
            stmt="index(x, length)",
            setup="from __main__ import index",
            label=label,
            sub_label="index",
            description="nojit",
            globals=globals_dict,
        )
        t_stack = benchmark.Timer(
            stmt="stack(x, length)",
            setup="from __main__ import stack",
            label=label,
            sub_label="stack",
            description="nojit",
            globals=globals_dict,
        )
        t_index_jit = benchmark.Timer(
            stmt="index_jit(x, length)",
            setup="from __main__ import index_jit",
            label=label,
            sub_label="index",
            description="jit",
            globals=globals_dict,
        )
        t_stack_jit = benchmark.Timer(
            stmt="stack_jit(x, length)",
            setup="from __main__ import stack_jit",
            label=label,
            sub_label="stack",
            description="jit",
            globals=globals_dict,
        )
        timers.extend([t_index, t_stack, t_index_jit, t_stack_jit])

    results = [t.blocked_autorange() for t in timers]

    compare = benchmark.Compare(results)
    compare.print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you say, `stack` is generally faster.

Usually we already have some tensors (output from a data loader or another `torch` operation) and can perform further `torch` operations on them. We try to avoid `for`-loops in pytorch so the heavily optimized pytorch functions can work faster with tensors on the gpu. A lot of overhead usually lies in the iteration of the for-loops.

You can try another benchmark where you have lready generated `out = [f(ii) for ii in range(length)]` and only perform the `stack`. Similarly, we try to write pytorch functions `f()` that support a batch as an input instead of a single sample (without using `for`-loops internally). If you do that, then you will only need to do an index assignment in a single call and that will be significantly faster as well.

This is the PyTorch way.